# How to play video in Android privately

Tags: android

I want to play video on my android app but I don't want anybody to be able to access it outside my app. I'm doing requests in JSON using rest api. I know I could just pass the URL in the JSON but anybody could access the video if they have the link. How can I be able to ensure that the video can only be available in my app. Here's my code

```
        String path="http://myserver.com/video.3gp";

      Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);

        VideoView video=
    (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
           video.setVideoURI(uri);
               video.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You're basically asking how to do DRM. If Hollywood can't figure out a way to do this that isn't trivially breakable, then you can't either.